# Updating cms page content for specific stores

Tags: magento-enterprise, cms, upgrade, install

Have two pages where i wanna update the content, both with the identifier 'home', one is on default(0) and the other is on store german(2).

If i do the following iteration, i get the correct pages but save() tries to save a new page what causes an exception. 
What's wrong or what can i change?

```
$oMagePageModel = Mage::getModel('cms/page');
foreach ($aHomePageTeaserContent as $iStoreId => $sHomePageTeaserContent) {
  $oMagePageModel->setStoreId($iStoreId);
  $oMagePageModel->load('home', 'identifier');

  $sHomePagePrevContent = $oMagePageModel->getContent();
  $oMagePageModel->setContent($sHomePagePrevContent . $sHomePageTeaserContent);

  $oMagePageModel->save();

  $oMagePageModel->clearInstance();
}
```

Comment: I'm guessing this has something to do with EE's CMS page version controls.

Comment: Version control isn't activated for that page, should be only a problem if active or? And the error i receive would be weird then: "A page URL key for specified store already exists."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the answer to it, first i thought loading by id could help so i changed the script to:

```
$oMagePageModel = Mage::getModel('cms/page');

foreach ($aHomePageTeaserContent as $iStoreId => $sHomePageTeaserContent) {
  $iPageId = $oMagePageModel->checkIdentifier('home', $iStoreId);
  $oPage   = $oMagePageModel->load($iPageId);

  $sPagePrevContent = $oPage->getContent();
  $oPage->setContent($sPagePrevContent . $sHomePageTeaserContent)->save();

  $oPage->clearInstance();
}
```

what looked much nicer to me but didn't work, too. After diggin deeper into the rabbit hole i saw, that `Mage_Cms_Model_Resource_Page getIsUniquePageToStores()` is the point where it comes to the problem.

In the first lines of the Method it checks `$object->hasStores()` and if the object as no stores, it sets it to `Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID` what exactly happens to my pages and trying to overwrite that page fires the exception.

So **the weird solution**, since i load the page by storeId and storeId is available in the page object, is setting the stores again with `$oPage->setData('stores', array($iStoreId));` before saving the page.